# IConfigurationListener parameter getInstance() method returns null

Tags: java, testing, testng, listener

I have a problem with `IConfigurationListener` from `org.testng package`. I would like to use it to perform some actions after method annotated with `@AfterTest`.

Test class:

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Listeners(Listener.class)
public class Tests {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("test 1");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void after(){
        System.out.println("After test");
    }
}
```

Listener class:

```
import org.testng.IConfigurationListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class Listener implements IConfigurationListener {

    public void onConfigurationSuccess(ITestResult itr) {
        System.out.println("Conf result: " + itr.getInstance()); // LINE
        System.out.println("Conf status: " + itr.getStatus());
    }

    public void onConfigurationFailure(ITestResult itr) {
    }

    public void onConfigurationSkip(ITestResult itr) {
    }
}
```

So the problem is that line (with comment `LINE`) returns `Conf result: null`. But next line return status of executed method so I'm confused. When I use `ITestListener` for the test method and perform `getInstance()` method on the result, then I receive an object which is not `null`. Is there any solution to use `IConfigurationListener` and get a result that is not `null`?

Comment: Which TestNG version do you use? Could you try with the current latest (6.10 or 6.10.1-SNAPSHOT)?

Comment: Yes I've tried with 6.10 version but result is the same

Comment: Ok, thanks. https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1319

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved by https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/1320 and will be available in the next TestNG release (post 6.10)

Comment: When next version will be available?

Comment: You can ask for it on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/testng-users